# How can I create one common client class, connect, and share that connection

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm designing a tool (in .net) which connects to an 3rd party web service API, and once connected creates a single client reference to that API. This single client instance needs to be reused over several other classes which will use the client as a proxy to execute their methods. Once finished, I need to close this single client's connection to the API.

I could just create a single instance and pass a reference to it in all the other classes. Or I could use a static class, but that doesn't really feel like the best way.

What's the best OOP design I can use to create and share this single client instance? Should I create a base class and inherit it in my other classes, and they somehow use the single common client reference?

I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds exactly like a singleton and I think is a good use case for one - see this article: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/c-singleton-pattern-vs-static-

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a WinForms application, making it static is OK. It is reused by the same thread all the time anyway.

You should still have some logic in place, though, to deal with the possibility that the shared proxy gets faulted. That happens when there is an Exception in the service you call. Once faulted, a proxy can no longer be used and must be replaced.

Therefore, a better approach is to create a singleton that exposes a Connection property which gets replaced in the get {} in case the underlying proxy gets faulted.